# Content behind custom UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I created a UINavigationController and a UIViewController. With this setup the view looks like this:

[image]

This is what I want. The content "Test Text" does not appear behind the status bar.

Now I created my own UINavigationBar in the UIViewControllers:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

   let newNavBar:UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 64))
   newNavBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   newNavBar.translucent = true
   self.view.addSubview(newNavBar)
}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

The content is behind the new navigation bar.

**How can I prevent the content from being behind the new navigation bar?**

Answer (score 0):

When you add Navigation Bar in view controller then NavigationBar will take 64pixel ( 20 pixel status bar and 44 pixel navigation bar ) so you need to start your layout after 64pixel from top.

Comment: But I want that the content scrolls under the navigation bar.

Comment: I guess that is not possible but you can put your code in scrollview and by default scroll it litter bit

Comment: How can I do that? And why is is not possible because it works well with the original nav bar?

Answer (score 0):

If your content is a `UIScrollView`, use the `contentInsets` property to adjust where your content starts, this makes the scrollview be able to scroll the specified amount of pixels "too far", and thus show your content immediately below your custom `UINavigationBar`.

If your content is not a `UIScrollview`, then just offset the content with a constraint (you could link it to an `IBOutlet`, so you can change it if you dynamically change from the old to the new `UINavigationBar`).